# Search in a 2D array... php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-key

I have this array:

$Fruit = array()

> $Fruit[$species][$property] = $value

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Green] => 4
            [Spots] => 3
            [Red] => 3
            [Spots] => 2
        )
```

Now I want to search if a key exists in the second array...

I tried this:

```
if (!array_key_exists($property, $Fruit->$species))
```

But it doesn't work...

Does anybody knows how to search inside an array of an array...?

Regards,
Thijs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array_key_exists($property, $Fruit[$species])
```

`->` is for objects, `[]` is for writing to and reading from arrays.

BTW, unless your values can be `null`, I'd recommend `isset` instead of `array_key_exists`:

```
isset($Fruit[$species][$property])
```

Should be more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You could reference to here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#92355

Answer (score 0):

The above works if all you need is a yes/no (true/false) answer on your search but it doesn't return the found element additional info (from the other array dimension, for instance).

Check out this loop in the PHP manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
and combine it with an `if` clause to get more

I'm not giving you a direct answer cause `foreach` is a part of PHP basics you need to learn.